# Changing Windows Form color from one to another

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm currently following the Head First C# but every so often I play around on my own. I ran into a situation that I'm unable to solve. I want to change `this.BackColor` from MediumBlue to step through green 0 - 255 and back to console with a button I/O. The issue is that I can't get the color to stop stepping and go back to MediumBlue.

```
private void btnClr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int fClr = 0;
        while (Visible)
        {
            if (fClr == 0)
            {
                fClr++;
                for (int nBackClr = 0; nBackClr < 255 && Visible; nBackClr++)
                {
                    this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(nBackClr, 255 - nBackClr, nBackClr);
                    Application.DoEvents();
                    Thread.Sleep(2);
                }
                for (int z = 255; z >= 0 && Visible; z--)
                {
                    this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(z, 255 - z, z);
                    Application.DoEvents();
                    Thread.Sleep(2);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                fClr--;
                this.BackColor = Color.MediumBlue;
                Application.DoEvents();
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Another thing I'd love to know is how to get the `BackColor` to go through the ENTIRE color palette.

EDIT: S/n *After applying JABFreeware's solution.* I added a breakpoint to see what was going on and `fClr` gets the value of 1 when I first click `btnClr_Click`. However when I click it again `fClr` gets 0 but then immediately gets 1 again. Not sure if this has to do with the `while (Visible)`.
..Head Scratcher..

Comment: I am still not sure what you are trying to accomplish. Could you please include some pictures?

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/4GuMLfg.jpg) is how it is in my form designer. When I click `btnClr_Click` (Form Colors) it cycles through green steps like here [link](http://i.imgur.com/D8he4Tg.jpg). I'm looking for a solution that when I click `btnClr_Click` again the `BackColor` will return to MediumBlue. I'm not sure why @JABFreeware's solution wouldn't solve but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easier to use a timer. That way your UI will remain responsive without using `DoEvents`.

```
const int ColorStep = 16;

private Timer _timer;
private int _r, _g, _b;

public frmRotateColors()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _r = 0;
    _g = 0;
    _b = 0;

    // Start the timer
    _timer = new Timer { Interval = 10 };
    _timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
    _timer.Start();
}

private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_b >= 256) { 
        _timer.Dispose(); // Stop the timer.
        this.BackColor = SystemColors.Control; // Reset the background color.
    } else {
        this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(_r, _g, _b);

        // Get next color
        _r += ColorStep;
        if (_r >= 256) {
            _r = 0;
            _g += ColorStep;
            if (_g >= 256) {
                _g = 0;
                _b += ColorStep;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I rotate through all the colors by increasing the red color. If I am out of range of red colors (0 - 255) I reset the red color and increase the green color. If the green color range is exceeded I reset the green color and increase the blue color. Finally, if the blue color range is exceeded I terminate the process.

Comment: Looking at it from a new solution I see that what you've accomplished and it can be used as a solution to step through multiple colors **but it doesn't stop either**. I'm trying to figure out how to apply your solution to my original project. Your code speeds up the steps from one exponentially per click. How would you use the same button to stop and return to the original BackColor? EDIT: I see once it reaches a certain point it reaches the terminate. This solution answers both questions. Thank you! :)

Comment: I do have one question but it's certainly not nessesary at this point; how would you use that solution to an I/O button. Simply, on click it cycles and doesn't stop. You must click it again to terminate.

Comment: `private bool _started;` and in the button click: `_started = !_started; if (_started) { start timer } else { stop timer; reset background }`. And also if `_b >= 256` set it to `0` in order to cycle through instead of terminating.

Comment: I got an error for `start timer`, `stop timer`, and `reset background`. Are these supposed to be methods or built in functions?

Comment: This is just pseudo code (a comment if you prefer). I have shown how to start and stop the timer in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is that `int fClr = 0;`is inside the button click event handler so every time they click the button, its reset to 0. Move the variable outside the click event.

Like this:

```
        int fClr = 0;
private void btnClr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        while (Visible)
        {
            if (fClr == 0)
            {
                fClr++;
                for (int nBackClr = 0; nBackClr < 255 && Visible; nBackClr++)
                {
                    this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(nBackClr, 255 - nBackClr, nBackClr);
                    Application.DoEvents();
                    Thread.Sleep(2);
                }
                for (int z = 255; z >= 0 && Visible; z--)
                {
                    this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(z, 255 - z, z);
                    Application.DoEvents();
                    Thread.Sleep(2);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                fClr--;
                this.BackColor = Color.MediumBlue;
                Application.DoEvents();
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I get what you're saying. But what about the `else` statement? How do I get that to work?

Comment: I tried to uprate your comment but I don't have enough reputation to do so. And the build still just goes and restarts the step through green. To put it simply it loops and doesn't stop.